# Get all possible US phone number chunks for given number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, algorithm

The US phone number format is:

```
(XXX) XXX-XXXX
```

For any given string (only digits) of length `0 < length <= 10` I want to get array of all possible chunks matching US phone number format.

For example:

```
Input: "54" 
Output: ["(54", "54", "54)", "5) 4", "5-4"]
```

For longer Input the Output is going to be much more complicated, and I think it would be stupid to type it by hand.

What I'm trying to do is to highlight phone number in a search result as I type it in my project.

I am using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight-words to achieve that - this package can take the array of `searchWords` to look for in specific text. I can't find any package or function to help me accomplish this task, neither I am fluent with regex (I'm not even sure whether it would help here)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If I type "54" and someone happens to have a number in the 541 area code (Oregon), why should it highlight the opening `(`? Why not just the `54`? (I get the `5-4` thing, but I think I'd just highlight the `5` and the `4`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's a client's request. More over there is still case like `5) 4`. Even if I was about to skip highlighting the no-digit signs, I still need to find this case and highlight only these 2 numbers. If I had a number like `(325) 425-345`, I don't want to have all `4s` and `5s` highlighted, only the first one in `5) 4`. So if I need to differentiate the case anyway, I may as well highlight the full occurrence.

Comment: And If I highlighted the full occurrence, it would be weird to skip the first bracket.

Comment: You don't really need permutations, do you? You just need to find the matching digits in the phone number list so you can highlight them, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think I should delete this tag, it's misleading, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your digits string into a regular expression that look for a series of: an optional non-digit (`\D?`) followed by the target digit followed by an optional non-digit. For instance, `"54"` becomes the regular expression `\D?5\D?\D?4\D?`.

Like this:

```
function format(num, digits) {
    // Since we're using a template literal, we have to escape the backslash
    // in `\D` for the regex constructor to see it
    const rex = new RegExp([...digits].map(digit => `\\D?${digit}\\D?`).join(""), "g");
    const result = num.replace(rex, m => `<span class="highlight">${m}</span>`);
    return result;
}
```

That seems to do the trick:

```js
const numbers = [
    "(321) 456-7890",
    "(098) 765-4321",
    "(541) 123-3456",
    "(354) 123-3456",
    "(335) 423-3456",
    "(231) 541-1234",
    "(231) 254-1234",
    "(231) 225-4234",
    "(231) 223-5434",
    "(231) 223-3544",
    "(231) 223-3454",
    "(231) 543-3454",
];

const input = "54";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `<div>
${numbers.map(num => "<div>" + format(num, input) + "</div>").join("")}
</div>`;

function format(num, digits) {
    const rex = new RegExp([...digits].map(digit => `\\D?${digit}\\D?`).join(""), "g");
    const result = num.replace(rex, m => `<span class="highlight">${m}</span>`);
    return result;
}
```

```css
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```